# Given below is my query in sql related to count and i want the expected output

Tags: mysql

I have written this query which provides me the total count of a particular song from the playlist_details table. (Example: Let's consider that the song name is "XYZ" and there are three entries with three different dates in the playlist_details table so my query shows me the output as "count 3". Now I further want to bifurcate this query such that I need one more column beside this count column which shows the three dates where the song xyz repeated in the table and because of which I got the count as 3.

```
SELECT
playlist_details.`EPISODE_TITLE` AS SongName,
songs_master.`ASSET_ID`,
song_rights_master.`CHANNEL_IDS` AS VChannels,
channel_master.`PLAYLIST_EXPORT_FILE_NAME`,
playlist_details.`DURATION`,
Count(*) AS Count,
programmes_master.`TITLE` as moviename,
songs_master.`SONG_TYPE`
FROM
playlist_details
INNER JOIN songs_master ON playlist_details.`ASSET_ID` = songs_master.`ASSET_ID`
INNER JOIN song_rights_master ON song_rights_master.`SONG_ID` = songs_master.`SONG_ID`
INNER JOIN channel_master ON channel_master.`CHANNEL_ID` = song_rights_master.`CHANNEL_IDS`
LEFT JOIN programmes_master ON songs_master.`PROGRAMME_ID` = programmes_master.`PROGRAMME_ID`
WHERE playlist_details.`EVENT_TYPE` = 'Song' AND
song_rights_master.`songs_agreements_master_id`='".$agreement."'
GROUP BY SongName
```

Current output:

```
+------------------------+
| SongName AssetID Total |
+------------------------+
| XYZ      000000  3     |
+------------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| SongName AssetID ScheduleDate Total |
+-------------------------------------+
| XYZ      000000  13-09-2019   3     |
|                  14-09-2019         |
|                  15-09-2019         |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know about the format of your expected output, you seem to want additional result rows with only the date inside? It will be hard to link them to your song if you have more than one result.. I suggest a solution that will output dates in unique rows as a string, separated with comas, for each result, like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| SongName AssetID ScheduleDate                       Total |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| XYZ      000000  13-09-2019,14-09-2019,15-09-2019   3     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

For this, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` which will concatenate values grouped with the `GROUP BY` (assuming the field is named `ScheduleDate` in your DB):

```
SELECT
playlist_details.`EPISODE_TITLE` AS SongName,
songs_master.`ASSET_ID`,
song_rights_master.`CHANNEL_IDS` AS VChannels,
channel_master.`PLAYLIST_EXPORT_FILE_NAME`,
playlist_details.`DURATION`,
Count(*) AS Count,
GROUP_CONCAT(playlist_details.`ScheduleDate`) as ScheduleDate,
programmes_master.`TITLE` as moviename,
songs_master.`SONG_TYPE`
FROM
playlist_details
INNER JOIN songs_master ON playlist_details.`ASSET_ID` = songs_master.`ASSET_ID`
INNER JOIN song_rights_master ON song_rights_master.`SONG_ID` = songs_master.`SONG_ID`
INNER JOIN channel_master ON channel_master.`CHANNEL_ID` = song_rights_master.`CHANNEL_IDS`
LEFT JOIN programmes_master ON songs_master.`PROGRAMME_ID` = programmes_master.`PROGRAMME_ID`
WHERE playlist_details.`EVENT_TYPE` = 'Song' AND
song_rights_master.`songs_agreements_master_id`='".$agreement."'
GROUP BY SongName
```

[See a simple example here](https://sqltest.net/#519313)

Comment: This Worked! But I used a slightly different method. I created a new function something like the one given below and separated the obtained date on new line each using the <br> and called this function inside the while loop which runs the mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: I am unble to paste the code here due to length limitations. But the query provided by you absolutely working fine. I just did those extra steps to separate the dates each on new line